# How do I return the number of unique digits in a positive integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example: unique_dig(123456) All unique
6

I'm trying to write code to have a function return how many unique numbers there are in a positive integer.

```
count = 0

for i in unique_digits:

    if count.has_key(i):

        count[i] += 1
else:

    count[i] = count + 1
```

Comment: If you are trying, where is your code?

Comment: I don't see anything in your post that shows your efforts. If you don't put it in your question, it doesn't exist. So this is a *plz givez me teh codez* post, and we don't do that here.

Comment: @KenWhite count = 0
 for i in unique_digits:
  if count.has_key(i):
   count[i] += 1
 else:
  count[i] = count + 1

Comment: Are you asking for the number of digits that appear only once in the number, or the number of digits that appear anywhere in the number?  What would you expect `335` to return: one or two?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh 2

Answer (score 2):

Convert the integer to a string, convert that string to a set of characters, then get the size of the set.

```
>>> N = 12334456
>>> len(set(str(N)))
6
```

I am indebted to Stefan Pochmann for teaching me something. (See the comments.)

Comment: @StefanPochmann: With a reputation of over 15,000, sir, you are being disingenuous! :) Nevertheless, I've edited my answer.

Comment: @BillBell Alright :-). I do see that from beginners more often and there I'm sure they just don't know/understand it. To be sure: The thing to know is not that `set` can take a string. That's just one case and shows no understanding of why. The thing to know is that `set` takes any *iterable* and that strings are iterable (and give you their characters). And that iteration is so fundamental and ubiquitous in Python (that's one of the reasons I love it).

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Often on SO someone will offer a comment phrased like your first in this exchange, ie, as a question. When I see this I usually think, 'Why wasn't the person making the comment more direct?' In my answer, it was obvious to you that `list` is unnecessary. You might instead have said, 'I think `list` is unnecessary.` It's *not* impolite. Beginners visiting here are often met with 'why' when they haven't the first clue how to answer.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Curious about `set` and strings. Didn't know that about strings at all. (Believe it or not.) Have used that characteristic of `set`, would never have thought to use it with string (for the obvious reason).

Comment: Right, my why-question was ambiguous. I knew the step was unnecessary, but I thought maybe you find it clearer that way or so. I'm sure I've seen that in similar cases before. I'll keep it in mind for the future and will now clean up my  comments. Anyway... so I guess when you wrote `list(str(...))`, you thought that `list` has special knowledge about strings that makes that work? It could for optimization, but "officially" it works for the same reason (strings being iterables).

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Having thought some more: I know strings are iterable, I've used that! Not clever enough to realise that you don't need to apply `list` to something that is already iterable. It's really a matter of noticing how to apply a characteristic in a different context. I have no excuse!

Comment: Heh. One of the things I noticed in Python is that when you have something you'd *like* to work (like `set(mystring)` or `0 <= i < n`), it often does. I think I've had quite a few moments of "Wait, what?! That works?!" with Python :-)

Comment: It's unbelievable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in pseudocode.  You should be able to convert this into Python without too much trouble.  Depending on the limitations (I assume this is homework of some kind), you may need to nest a second loop to check each char against the `arrayOfUniqueCharacters`.

```
someInputString = "abracadabra"
emptyArrayOfUniqueCharacters = []

FOR char IN someInputString
    IF char NOT IN arrayOfUniqueChars
        APPEND char TO arrayOfUniqueChars
RETURN length OF arrayOfUniqueChars
```