# How do I return the number of unique digits in positive integer

Tags: python

Here is what I currently have:

```
unique = 0

while n > 0:    
    last, n = n % 10, n // 10    
        if not has_digit(n, last):    
            unique += 1    
    return unique
```

I'm trying to have it so for every unique number in an integer, it outputs how many unique numbers there are.

For Example:

```
unique_digits(123456) = 6    
unique_digits(112222) = 2

>>> unique_digits(8675309) # All are unique
    7
    >>> unique_digits(1313131) # 1 and 3
    2
    >>> unique_digits(13173131) # 1, 3, and 7
    3
    >>> unique_digits(10000) # 0 and 1
    2
    >>> unique_digits(101) # 0 and 1
    2
    >>> unique_digits(10) # 0 and 1
    2
    """
```

Comment: It would probably be easier to turn the number into a String and count the characters. And what specifically are you asking?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm asking to make a function on how to count how many times a unique number appears in an integer. If it appears once, +1. If it appears 5 times, still only +1

Comment: This questions was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48273921/how-do-i-return-the-number-of-unique-digits-in-a-positive-integer/48274012#48274012 moments ago.

Comment: @Friender0140 I got that, but what specifically about that problem do you need help with? This is rather broad.

Comment: What's `has_digit`? Why do you have a `return` statement outside of a function?

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm trying to use the python built in function (has_digit) and its not outside the function, just a formatting error

Comment: doesn't 56 count as a unique number? or 456?  Do you mean unique digit?

Comment: @Alexander meant digit

Comment: I've never heard of a built-in `has_digit` function. Where did you find it? There is a `str` method `isdigit`.

Answer (score 5):

First make a string out of it, then get unique values by making a `set` and 
then count with `len`.

```
len(set(str(122226)))
# 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to convert the numbers into `string` and pass it into `set`. This will only retain unique digits.

```
>>> len( set(str(num)) )
```

**EDIT :**

As a function,

```
def unique_digits(num): 
    return len( set(str(num)) )
```

#driver code :

```
>>> print(unique_digits(123456))
6
>>> print(unique_digits(112222))
2
```

Comment: I keep getting nothing in my doctest when I do it this way.

Comment: @Friender0140 What doctest? Please include all relevant information in your question.

Comment: Um, you have to `print` the `unique_dig`

Comment: @KaushikNP I'm trying to do this: unique_digits = len( set(str(n)) )
print(unique_digits(28212)) and getting none

Comment: Um no... You have to do just  `unique_digits = len( set(str(28212)) )` `print(unique_digits)`

Comment: @KaushikNP How can I make it so any number I put as num would print the output im striving to get. Also I'm getting an error saying function unique_digits at 0x00000187c0541400

Comment: Ok. For better clarity, I'll write the whole function itself.

Comment: @Friender0140 : pls check the edit

Comment: @KaushikNP I have this right now:                                                       
        def unique_digits(n):
 return len(set(str(n)) 

print (unique_digits(123456))

print (unique_digits(112222))                                                                                           Would this work? Not sure how to format it in Lines.

Comment: @KaushikNP I'm using what u put in ur edit but its still giving me errors

Comment: Can you pls mention what the error is that you are getting?

Comment: @KaushikNP These are my doctests: >>> unique_digits(8675309) # All are unique
 7
 >>> unique_digits(1313131) # 1 and 3
 2
 >>> unique_digits(13173131) # 1, 3, and 7
 3
 >>> unique_digits(10000) # 0 and 1
 2
 >>> unique_digits(101) # 0 and 1
 2
 >>> unique_digits(10) # 0 and 1
 2
 """ and im getting EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: @KaushikNP how can i put my comments in lines so they are more readable?

Comment: @Friender0140 Don't bury important information in the comments on an answer. Put it into your question, where it belongs.

Comment: As @PM2Ring mentioned, the info you are providing is not enough. What doctest? Pls include properly formatted info in the question as an Edit.

Comment: @KaushikNP Sorry about that, my doctests are edited in the question

Comment: @Friender0140 : sorry buddy, but am not sure about Doctest. You'll have to cosult someone else on this. Maybe PM2Ring can help you out there. Continue this thread in the Question's comments section for better response.